# Translating to english a Japanese word that phonetically sounds like "Ish" or "Hish" or "Yish" etc

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I have been watching some old Japanese movies and anime with sub titles. I don't speak or under stand Japanese and rely totally on the English subtitles.

I have seen a word used a couple of times that is never translated in the subtitles. It sounds like ish or hish or yish or something like that. None of the actors speak it distinctly enough for me to be sure how it sounds phonetically.

In all cases the word is spoken under the persons breath, and not directed to another person.

The context it is used in is

1. a lady is washing her arms at a sink. As she completes soaping one arm she moves to the next arm and says the word ish or hish or yish or something like that.
2. a guy climbs out of a swimming pool or large bathing pool and says the word ish or hish or yish or something like that as he exits the water because he is called out by the attendant .

Does anyone have any idea what this word is? I have tried to speak the word into Google Translate on a phone but it does not come up with anything that seems to fit the action occurring.

Comment: Is there a link to the anime on a website where it can be viewed or can you add the anime's title and episode with timestamp so those interested can look up the scenes you are describing?

Comment: Gotta hear it myself to be sure but it was probably よいしょ、おいしょ、よっし、よしっ、etc.   Those are rarely enunciated by us native speakers in real life.

Comment: @ l'électeur i think you have it. Google translate translates "よいしょ、おいしょ、よっし、よしっ、The google speech pronunciation comparison leads me to believe its most likely "よし、 or よしっ" I have noticed google always has a more formal distinct pronunciation than live speaking, but as the meaning translates to "alright/well" it seems to fit the action ive seen occurring. thanks

Answer (score 2):

@l'électeur I think you have it. Google Translate translates "よいしょ、おいしょ、よっし、よしっ

The Google speech pronunciation comparison leads me to believe it's most likely "よし" or "よしっ" I have noticed google always has a more formal distinct pronunciation than live speaking, but as the meaning translates to "alright/well" it seems to fit the action I've seen occurring.